# get object from list that is in another list of objects

Tags: java, lambda

so, i have 2 object

```
public class Vehiculo {
    private Integer idVeiculo;
    private List<OpcionesColores> colores;
    private String marca;
    //getter and setter
```

and 

`public class OpcionesColores {
    private String puerta;
    private String techo;
    private String rines;
//getter and setter`

now, the main class

`package cl.poc;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class Recorrido {

    private static final org.slf4j.Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Recorrido.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        OpcionesColores color1 = new OpcionesColores("Rojo", "Azul", "Negro");
        OpcionesColores color2 = new OpcionesColores("Rojo", "Amarillo", "Black");
        OpcionesColores color3 = new OpcionesColores("Rojo", "Blanco", "Marron");
        OpcionesColores color4 = new OpcionesColores("Rojo", "Azul", "Negro");
        List<OpcionesColores> colores = new ArrayList<>();
        colores.add(color1);
        colores.add(color2);
        colores.add(color4);
        List<OpcionesColores> colores2 = new ArrayList<>();
        colores2.add(color1);
        colores2.add(color2);
        colores2.add(color3);
        colores2.add(color4);
        List<OpcionesColores> colores3 = new ArrayList<>();
        colores3.add(color1);
        colores3.add(color2);
        colores3.add(color4);

        Vehiculo auto = new Vehiculo(1, colores, "mazda");
        Vehiculo auto2 = new Vehiculo(2, colores2, "nissan");
        Vehiculo auto3 = new Vehiculo(3, colores3, "toyota");

        List<Vehiculo> autos = new ArrayList<>();
        autos.add(auto);
        autos.add(auto2);
        autos.add(auto3);

//        autos.stream().forEach(
//            (autosLoop) -> colores.stream().filter(c -> c.getTecho().equalsIgnoreCase("blanco")).collect(
//                Collectors.toList()));

//        autos.stream().forEach((autosLoop) -> colores.stream().forEach(System.out::println));

        Vehiculo vehiculoFinal = new Vehiculo();

        for (Vehiculo vehiculo : autos) {
            for (OpcionesColores opcionesColores : vehiculo.getColores()) {
                if (opcionesColores.getTecho().equalsIgnoreCase("Blanco")) {
                    vehiculoFinal = vehiculo;
                    System.out.println(opcionesColores);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(vehiculoFinal);

    }

}`

i need to get the "vehiculo" with "OpcionesColores.techo" is "blanco". i tried using lambda expresion but not working to me.
I know if i'll use another instance of OpcionesColores and after that remove of vehiculo all items are not blanco is ok, but i need a shortly way to do it

thanks!

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code and edit your post to use the Markdown for code blocks, rather than HTML - it will avoid all the odd grey boxes.

Comment: `autos.stream().filter(v -> v.getColores().stream().anyMatch(c ->  c.getTecho().equalsIgnoreCase("Blanco"))).findAny()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have to handle potential NullPointerException

```
    Vehiculo vehiculoFinal2 = autos.stream().filter(Objects::nonNull).filter(vehiculo ->
            Objects.nonNull(vehiculo.getColores()) && vehiculo.getColores().stream().filter(Objects::nonNull)
                    .anyMatch(opcionesColores -> 
                            Objects.nonNull(opcionesColores.getTecho()) && 
                                    opcionesColores.getTecho().equalsIgnoreCase("Blanco"))
    ).findFirst().orElse(null);
```